# Android shared memory and memory mapping

Tags: android, c++

I have written a code in Cpp using Android shared memory api's. i used the ASharedMemory_create api from android ndk paltform-26(libandroid.so for arm64 architecture) and compiled the code . After successful compilation , while running the program i got the memory mapping failed for the same .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sharedmem.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
     int a = ASharedMemory_create("Memory",128);
 cout << " The file descriptor in hex: " << hex << a << endl;
 cout << " The file descriptor in dec: " << dec << a << endl;
 size_t memsize =ASharedMemory_getSize(a);
 cout << " The file descriptor size: " << memsize << endl;

 void *mapper= mmap(0,128,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,a,0);

 cout << "the mapped value is : " << mapper << endl;

if (MAP_FAILED == mapper )
{
  cout << "mmap failed";
}

return 0;

}
```

case :1
The file descriptor in hex: f4244c0(random values)
The file descriptor in dec: -198809920(random values)
The file descriptor size :40961573537
The mapped value is : 0x7ffeeefw7dsd(random values)
The mapped value is : 0xffffffffffffffff
mmap failed

case :2
The file descriptor in hex: f4244c0(random values)
The file descriptor in dec: 1273477444
The file descriptor size :1273477444 (size and fd are same if fd is positive)
The mapped value is : 0x7ffeeefw7dsd(random values)
The mapped value is : 0xffffffffffffffff
mmap failed

Comment: i tried the type casting and still got the same error. To add furthur i am bit curious how my ASharedMemory_create and ASharedMemory_getSize api provides me the same output for the positive fd.

Comment: Currently i am running my android domain in a hypervised qualcomm snapdragron board

Comment: so you have two different processes? one for writing and one for reading?

Comment: yes i do .. but my actual problem is why i cant mmap my file descriptor to the process virutal memory space

Comment: i am creating an Andriod shared momory using ashmem. i have two apis in the above code .one is to create and other is to find the size. but while i am executing this code both the apis gave the same value..for eg:file desciptor is some random value but the size is also the same random value..how can the size be some random value?????is the api itself is wrong??? den when i tried to mmap the file descriptor i am receiving bad file descriptor error also...i need to know whether my apis are correct.

Comment: Is it possible to do dat with failed mmap?

Comment: if you receive `MAP_FAILED` what does `perror()` function say?

Comment: i am getting bad file descriptor error for the same.

Comment: The issue is resolved ..looks like the api in the libandriod.so (ndk platform-26) is somehow wrong..i used the Cpp implementation directly and got the expected results.

Comment: https://github.com/pelya/android-shmem use the api's inside cutils for the expected output/.